# Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) + MySQL 5.1 + Hibernate - OpenShift - No persistence unit found

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat7, jta, openshift

Every time I try to reach my app on OpenShift I receive the "No Persistence provider for EntityManager named appname" error.

I have been struggling to resolve this problem for two consecutive days and I still did not find an answer.

I have tried all the possible configuration I found over the web.

My current configuration:

#### META-INF\persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="appname" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/comp/env/jdbc/appname</jta-data-source>

    <class>myorg.mypackage.MyClass</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory" /> 
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

#### .openshift\config\context.xml

```
<Context>
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" maxWait="-1" name="jdbc/appname" password="mypass"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://myurl:3306/appname"
    username="myuser" />
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

#### .openshift\config\server.xml

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="false" autoDeploy="true">
    <Context docBase="appname" path="/appname" reloadable="true"                    source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:appname" />
</Host>
```

#### The exception

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named appname
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at org.andvicoso.shopand.model.dao.base.GenericDaoJPA.<init>(GenericDaoJPA.java:20)
    at org.andvicoso.shopand.model.dao.ProductDaoJPA.<init>(ProductDaoJPA.java:8)
    at org.andvicoso.shopand.web.ViewHelper.getProductDao(ViewHelper.java:31)
    at org.andvicoso.shopand.web.ViewHelper.getHighlights(ViewHelper.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:87)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:67)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
    at org.apache.jasper.el.JspValueExpression.getValue(JspValueExpression.java:106)
    at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fset_005f6(index_jsp.java:260)
```

Can anyone help me???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue and found that my META-INF was under src\main\java which was causing this error. When I moved META-INF to src\main\resources... it worked.